# php composer.json JSON comments substitute

Tags: php, json, composer-php, key, comments

Since JSON does not allow to comment its content I'm not able to put any snippets or other additional information into composer.json that will not be taken as a data by php composer.

Is there any particular key name in composer.json file under which I may store some random text without interfering composer interpreting the composer.json file?

I want to store text and arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it's valid JSON, you can use [`extra`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra):

> Arbitrary extra data for consumption by scripts.
>
> This can be virtually anything.